# Get Shipping address from Ebay API

Tags: php, object, ebay-api

I have an object returned from ebay trading api like bellow,

```
 $address = $order_data->ShippingAddress;
 print_r($address);
```

**Result**

```
DTS\eBaySDK\Trading\Types\AddressType Object
(
    [values:DTS\eBaySDK\Types\BaseType:private] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Test User
            [Street1] => address
            [Street2] => 
            [CityName] => city
            [StateOrProvince] => BUCKINGHAMSHIRE
            [Country] => GB
            [CountryName] => United Kingdom
            [Phone] => 1 800 111 1111
            [PostalCode] => HP19 3EQ
            [AddressID] => 7725220
            [AddressOwner] => eBay
            [ExternalAddressID] => 
        )

    [attachment:DTS\eBaySDK\Types\BaseType:private] => Array
        (
            [data] => 
            [mimeType] => 
        )

)
```

I need to access Name,Street1 etc from this object.
I try to access it like `$address->Name` , `$address[0]->Name` ,`$address->Name[0]` .but not getting the data i wanted.

Comment: Based on the information shown by print_r($address) then echo $address->Name should display the value "Test User". At the moment I can't see any reason as to why it wouldn't. You may need to explain what you mean when you say "but not getting the data i wanted" . Do you mean nothing is been returned or is the wrong information present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `toArray()` method like,

```
$address_array = $address->toArray();
print_r($address_array); // address as array
```